# How close other element when clicked using .slideToggle

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make an accordion menu, how ever, i need the menus to open only 1. how do i close other li when clicked?

below is the code i use for toggling the menu. How do i target all other li to close when an li is clicked.

```
<li class="cat_parent">
  <h2 class="head par_title">Books</h2>
  <div class="content">01</div>
  <div class="content">02</div>
</li>
<li class="cat_parent">
  <h2 class="head par_title">Magazine</h2>
  <div class="content">01</div>
  <div class="content">02</div>
  <div class="content">03</div>
  <div class="content">04</div>
</li>

$(document).ready(function(){
   ('.head').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).closest('li').find('.content').slideToggle();
   });
});
```

your help is much appreciated!

Comment: You do know about http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ I guess?

Comment: in your function that opens the the section you want, also close the others... you can target them with `$(this).siblings` I think...

Comment: use addClass and removeClass

Comment: even better use toggleClass

Comment: Also this can be achieved by using show() and hide() ...

Comment: simply do `$("li.yourclassname").hide();` to close all `li`s. then show desired `li`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$('.cat_parent').find('div').hide();

$('.head').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).siblings().slideDown('slow');
      $(this).parents('.cat_parent').siblings().find('div').slideUp('slow');
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kanishka_bandara/GfyZf/